# Select a value based on From and To Range values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table in SQL Server 2012 Database called TblAccttAssistant. It has the below Data Values as shown in image:-[image: TblAccttAssistant]

I want to use Sql Query to Select a **Single** value based for *PPO_From* and *PPO_To* column values range:

```
      Select * from TblAccttAssistant  where (ppo_from >=2500 ANd ppo_to<=2500)
```

I have to provide a single value 2500 to query. 
It is getting 0 No of Rows.

Comment: your condition result will 0 ppo_to<=2500, all ppo_to above this

Comment: First of all, what is your requirement becuase the query is perfect on it's way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the BETWEEN operator?

```
SELECT * FROM TblAccttAssistant WHERE 2500 BETWEEN ppo_from AND ppo_to
```

Your query doesn't work because there is no row satisfying both of your WHERE-conditions.

Comment: The one you have provided is a `shorthand` for the one OP has provided so they both are identical.

Comment: No it's not identical, it returns the first row

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from TblAccttAssistant  where (ppo_from <=2500 ANd ppo_to>=2500)
```